# Do azure service principal names need to be unique tenant wide or subscription wide?

Tags: azure

Naming is important because it can make environmental config more of a pain if not done correctly.

In AWS IAM user names are unique to the AWS account. So if I have a dev and a prod account I can create an IAM user named "my-app" in both. The name of the user is the same- this can make configuration easier

Do my Azure SPNs need to be unique tenant wide or just unique to a subscription which I might have for each environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure service principal names are not so important. The identifier of azure service principal here is application ID or object ID . You can create multiple service principals with a same name, but their application ID or object ID will be different.

application IDs or object IDs are GUIDs on Azure platform.

Comment: you could also add that you can have others `identiferUris` to uniquely identify your service principal in the same AAD tenant. But yes service principal are unique at the tenant level.